# Type mismatch using pattern matching on constructors scala

Tags: scala, generics, pattern-matching, higher-kinded-types

I'm trying to define a HKT in Scala (a generic stream) and I'm not sure why I'm getting a type mismatch error while trying to implement the exists method:

Here's my code so far

```
sealed trait SmartStream[+A] 
case object Nil extends SmartStream[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](h : () => A, t : () => SmartStream[A]) extends SmartStream[A]

object SmartStream {
  def nil[A] : SmartStream[A] = Nil

  def cons[A](h : => A, t : => SmartStream[A]) : SmartStream[A] = {
    lazy val g = h
    lazy val u = t
    Cons(() => g, () => u)
  }

  def apply[A](as: A*) : SmartStream[A] = {
    if (as.isEmpty) nil
    else cons( as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
  }

  def exists[A](p : A => Boolean) : Boolean = {
    this match {
      case Nil => false
      case Cons(h, t) => p(h()) || t().exists(p)
    }
  }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
    ScalaFiddle.scala:21: error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : ScalaFiddle.this.Nil.type
 required: ScalaFiddle.this.SmartStream.type
        case Nil => false
             ^
ScalaFiddle.scala:22: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : ScalaFiddle.this.Cons[A]
 required: ScalaFiddle.this.SmartStream.type
        case Cons(h, t) => p(h()) || t().exists(p)
             ^
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You're putting `exists()` in the `SmartStream` object (i.e. singleton). That means `this` is type `SmartStream.type` and can never be anything else.

If you move `exists()` to the trait, and remove the type parameter, things will compile.

```
sealed trait SmartStream[+A] {
  def exists(p : A => Boolean) : Boolean = {
    this match {
      case Nil => false
      case Cons(h, t) => p(h()) || t().exists(p)
    }
  }
}
```

There may be other deficiencies in the design, but at least this compiles.